# Chess game gives invalid moves

Tags: java, debugging, chess

I'm writing a chess game, but I keep running into a bug. When I ask for valid moves, my program returns some spots that shouldn't be valid.

This is my current code

```
public enum PieceType {
    PAWN('p', (piece, pieceOnEndTile, board, move) -> {
        PieceTeam team = piece.getTeam();
        int dx = move.getdx();
        int dy = move.getdy();
        final boolean willKill = pieceOnEndTile != null && pieceOnEndTile.getTeam() != team;
        int direction = -1; // to distinguish between the dy of black and white
        if (team == PieceTeam.BLACK) {
            direction = 1; // for black pawns, dy is positive, for white it's
                            // negative
        }
        dy = dy * direction;
        boolean isKilling = willKill && dy == 1 && abs(dx) == 1;
        boolean isMoving1 = dy == 1 && dx == 0 && pieceOnEndTile == null;
        boolean isMoving2 = dy == 2 && dx == 0 && pieceOnEndTile == null && !piece.hasBeenMoved();

        return isKilling || isMoving1 || isMoving2;

    }), BISHOP('b', (piece, pieceOnEndTile, board, move) -> {
        PieceTeam team = piece.getTeam();
        int dx = move.getdx();
        int dy = move.getdy();
        return abs(dy) == abs(dx) && tileIsEmptyOrEnemy(pieceOnEndTile, team) && !pieceInWay(board, move, team);
    }), KNIGHT('k', (piece, pieceOnEndTile, board, move) -> {
        PieceTeam team = piece.getTeam();
        int dx = move.getdx();
        int dy = move.getdy();
        boolean isCorrectMove = (abs(dy) == abs(2 * dx) || (abs(dx) == abs(2 * dy))) && abs(dy) <= 2 && abs(dx) <= 2;

        return isCorrectMove && tileIsEmptyOrEnemy(pieceOnEndTile, team);
    }), ROOK('r', (piece, pieceOnEndTile, board, move) -> {
        PieceTeam team = piece.getTeam();
        int dx = move.getdx();
        int dy = move.getdy();
        return (abs(dy) >= 1 && abs(dx) == 0 || abs(dx) >= 1 && abs(dy) == 0) && tileIsEmptyOrEnemy(pieceOnEndTile, team) && !pieceInWay(board, move, team);
    }), QUEEN('Q', (piece, pieceOnEndTile, board, move) -> {
        PieceTeam team = piece.getTeam();
        int dx = move.getdx();
        int dy = move.getdy();
        return (abs(dy) == abs(dx) || abs(dy) >= 1 && abs(dx) == 0 || abs(dx) >= 1 && abs(dy) == 0) && tileIsEmptyOrEnemy(pieceOnEndTile, team) && !pieceInWay(board, move, team);
    }), KING('K', (piece, pieceOnEndTile, board, move) -> {
        PieceTeam team = piece.getTeam();
        int dx = move.getdx();
        int dy = move.getdy();
        return abs(dy) <= 1 && abs(dx) <= 1 && tileIsEmptyOrEnemy(pieceOnEndTile, team);
    });

    public final IsLegalMove isLegalMove;
    public final char representation;

    private PieceType(final char representation, final IsLegalMove isLegalMove) {
        this.isLegalMove = isLegalMove;
        this.representation = representation;
    }

    private static boolean tileIsEmptyOrEnemy(GamePiece piece, PieceTeam currentTeam) {
        return piece == null || piece.getTeam() != currentTeam;
    }

    private static boolean pieceInWay(GamePiece[][] board, Move move, PieceTeam team) {
        int changerx = (int) Math.signum(move.getdx());
        int changery = (int) Math.signum(move.getdy());
        for (int x = move.start.x + changerx, y = move.start.y + changery; x < move.end.x; x += changerx, y += changery) {
            if (board[y][x] != null) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public static interface IsLegalMove {
        public boolean call(GamePiece piece, GamePiece pieceOnEndTile, GamePiece[][] board, Move move);
    }

}
```

The problem, I think, is in the `pieceInWay` method. I've been staring at it forever, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Could it be `y = move.start.y + changery`, y is not declared an int. What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Once programs get complex, you really need a test harness to keep everything working.  Simple methods like `testPawn()`, `testBishop()` and `testPieceInWay()` will help you isolate errors and avoid complicated debugging.  [Some info here.](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html)

Comment: Which spots? For which pieces? In which board states?

Comment: @JamesBuck it's not an error, some pieces (for example the queen) only correctly stop in some directions. In the  queen class, it only works in the upper right and lower right directions.

Comment: @Kyranstar you are only checking if `x < move.end.x` in your for loop condition, maybe it's something to do with that.

Comment: @Kyranstar try changing the for loop to be `for (int x = move.start.x + changerx, y = move.start.y + changery; x < move.end.x || y < move.end.y; x += changerx, y += changery)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by writing out actual cases for each of the 8 directions, and it seems to work now.

```
public static boolean pieceInWay(final GamePiece[][] board, final Move move) {
        final int changerx = (int) Math.signum(move.getdx());
        final int changery = (int) Math.signum(move.getdy());
        switch (Direction.getFromDelta(changerx, changery)) {
        case DOWN:
            for (int y = move.start.y + 1; y < move.end.y; y++) {
                if (board[y][move.start.x] != null) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            break;
        case DOWN_LEFT:
            for (int y = move.start.y + 1, x = move.start.x - 1; y < move.end.y; y++, x--) {
                if (board[y][x] != null) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            break;
        case DOWN_RIGHT:
            for (int y = move.start.y + 1, x = move.start.x + 1; y < move.end.y; y++, x++) {
                if (board[y][x] != null) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            break;
        case LEFT:
            for (int x = move.start.x - 1; x > move.end.x; x--) {
                if (board[move.start.y][x] != null) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            for (int x = move.start.x + 1; x < move.end.x; x++) {
                if (board[move.start.y][x] != null) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            break;
        case UP:
            for (int y = move.start.y - 1; y > move.end.y; y--) {
                if (board[y][move.start.x] != null) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            break;
        case UP_LEFT:
            for (int y = move.start.y - 1, x = move.start.x - 1; y > move.end.y; y--, x--) {
                if (board[y][x] != null) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            break;
        case UP_RIGHT:
            for (int y = move.start.y - 1, x = move.start.x + 1; y > move.end.y; y--, x++) {
                if (board[y][x] != null) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public static interface IsLegalMove {
        public boolean call(GamePiece piece, GamePiece pieceOnEndTile, GamePiece[][] board, Move move);
    }

    private static enum Direction {
        UP(0, -1),
        UP_RIGHT(1, -1),
        RIGHT(1, 0),
        DOWN_RIGHT(1, 1),
        DOWN(0, 1),
        DOWN_LEFT(-1, 1),
        LEFT(-1, 0),
        UP_LEFT(-1, -1);

        public final int dx;
        public final int dy;

        private Direction(final int dx, final int dy) {
            this.dx = dx;
            this.dy = dy;
        }

        public static Direction getFromDelta(final int dx, final int dy) {
            for (final Direction d : values()) {
                if (d.dx == dx && d.dy == dy) {
                    return d;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok. The cracker is as usual the knight. Do you know how a knight moves?

Comment: @ott Yes, but I don't need to use this method with the knight because the knight jumps, rather than slides.

Comment: Thinking over it, that method needs refactoring. What's there at b5? Can I capture it to increase my score? Can I move to c4 to create another threat?

Comment: On a chess board the columns are ordered a..h and the rows are ordered 1..8. And `b5` is `b5`.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. This method is supposed to be used to check whether a move in a straight line is valid, or whether there are pieces in the way.